# Read Title and Table from Direct Editor in a MSI with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, datatable, windows-installer, title

hey i search an Option to give me out the Titles from the Columns in a Table and the Table itself.

i tried it with getType().InvokeMember but i dont know is this the right Way to find the Titles.

I use this code to find all Values in a defined Table and Column but so its very undynamic and i must do this for all tables in the MSI data.

```
function Get-Msiinfo {
param (
    [IO.FileInfo] $FilePath
)

try {
    $windowsInstaller = New-Object -com WindowsInstaller.Installer

    $database = $windowsInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "OpenDatabase", "InvokeMethod", $Null, 
            $windowsInstaller, @($FilePath.FullName, 0)
        )
#Select all Values in the Table "Property" but without Columnstitels
    $q = "SELECT * FROM Property"
    $View = $database.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "OpenView", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $database, ($q)
        )

    $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null)

    $record = $View.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "Fetch", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null
        )

    while($record -ne $null)
    {

        $shortcut = $record.GetType().InvokeMember(
                "StringData", "GetProperty", $Null, $record, 2
            )
        $shortcut

        $record = $View.GetType().InvokeMember(
                "Fetch", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null
            )
    }


    $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Close", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null)

    #return $shortcut

} catch {
    throw "Failed to get MSI Values, error was: {0}." -f $_
}
}

Get-Msiinfo -FilePath Path your msi
```

Thanks for answer and sorry for my bad english

Comment: I can't really understand your exact needs but I would look at this: https://github.com/heaths/psmsi/releases

Comment: Thank you, that is what i Need :) You help me alot